# Cannot install Python Jupyter or Jupyterlabs on Windows due to missing pywin32

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When I try to install Jupyter using "pip install jupyter" I get the error:

***No matching distribution found for pywin32***, as follows:

```
Collecting pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->n
bconvert->jupyter) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter)
```

The same thing happens if I try "pip install pywin32" or "pip install pypiwin32".

I am using Python 3.8.2, PIP 19.0.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubles with installing jupyter in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699107/troubles-with-installing-jupyter-in-pycharm)

Comment: Go to Linux. Windows works in mysterious ways

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Python 3.7.6 solved the problem, as mentioned in the post mentioned in the comment by @Kalana.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing `pip install pywin32==225` will fix the issue
on Python 3.8 (and even 3.9). There is a discussion on the topic in [this thread](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1431)